# Remove entity type without module uninstall

Tags: 8, entities

I created entity type my_entity in my module. But now I don't need this entity anymore and I want to completely remove it without module's uninstall. I want to remove both definition and all database related tables or data. I thought about using `\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager->uninstallEntityType('my_entity')` in `hook_update_N`, but I can't use it because entity's definition will be removed.

Could anyone help me, and give advice how to delete both definition and database data?

*UPD*: I created an issue on drupal.org about this https://www.drupal.org/node/2655162

Answer (score 11):

The argument for entityDefinitionUpdateManager->uninstallEntityType() is an EntityTypeInterface, not a string.

Drupal stores the last known state of an entity type, you can get it like this:

```
$entity_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$entity_type = $entity_update_manager->getEntityType('your_entity_type_id');
$entity_update_manager->uninstallEntityType($entity_type);
```

Note that this is using the enitty definitions update manager to get the entity type definition, not the runtime entity type manager.

The field definitions are also read from state and both the entity type and field definitions are purged afterwards.

Comment: Simplifed the code example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code works only if definition is present in code. If definition is removed from code I get the following error: `The "my_entity" entity type does not exist.`

Comment: Are you sure that you did get the entity type definition from the definition update manager and not the entity manager? It should definitely work. If not  then that's a core bug.

Comment: Yes, my code is the following: `/**
 * Change definitions of entity tables.
 */
function mymodule_update_8101() {
  $entity_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $entity_type = $entity_update_manager->getEntityType('my_entity');
  $entity_update_manager->uninstallEntityType($entity_type);
}`
And it works only if entity definition is present in code.

Comment: Open a core issue then. I think there is no test for this yet, as it is tricky to reproduce in a test. We need to add one. Try to figure out more about that error, a stack trace of the exception would be good to have. Maybe the problem is in some module that reacts to the event.

Comment: Thank for your help. I will gather all information, check everything one more time and will create an issue.

Comment: Yeah, weird things happen when the type definition has been deleted from code. I encountered similar things. Looking forward to the core issue being opened; update hooks in general right now are pretty confusing. I think one thing you can do as a workaround is to specify the entity type definition fresh in your update hook (copy it from the old code), and _then_ uninstall it. See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fillpdf/tree/fillpdf.install?h=8.x-4.x#n39 for a basic idea of how to do the field-adding part in an update hook.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2655162 - I created an issue about this problem.
@wizonesolutions Thanks for your help, I will try it. But I think it will remove only data which is defined only in baseFieldDefinitions(), but other code may want to react on entity uninstall.

Comment: I can confirm that the suggested code from Berdir works now with Drupal 8.3.0. Just define a function with the code from berdir's post and execute it via Drush: drush php-eval "dropEntity();". And voilà: the database table from the entity is deleted and the entity uninstalled.

Comment: In 9.5.2 i removed all the code from my custom module related to a custom entity (entities of this type had already been removed). I tried the code above in drush and it crashes. I put the entity code back and the function now runs; but if i then remove the entity code again - my site is still broken with: entity type does not exist error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try

```
function MODULE_NAME_post_update_8104(&$sandbox) {
  // Making sure the entities are deleted.
  try {
    $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('ENTITY_TYPE');
    $entities = $storage_handler->loadMultiple();
    $storage_handler->delete($entities);
  }
  catch (PluginException $e) {
    \Drupal::logger('MODULE_NAME')->error($e->getMessage());
  }
  catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
    \Drupal::logger('MODULE_NAME')->error($e->getMessage());
  }
  // Uninstalling the entity afterwards.
  $entity_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $entity_type = $entity_update_manager->getEntityType('ENTITY_TYPE');
  $entity_update_manager->uninstallEntityType($entity_type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all the entities of that type.
2. Remove the entity type declaration
3. Rebuild the caches

Comment: Unfortunatly, everything isn't so easy. Despite of entity declaration there is also data in database(for example base data) which should be deleted.

Comment: @MariaKvitova that needs to be done manually. I'll update the answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: That's not correct, see my answer. This is absolutely possible.